# MVC EditorFor templates not used when calling controller from another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, editorfor, editorfortemplate

Within an MVC project we have an area with a controller SomeController returning a partial view containing EditorFor statements, each with their own template.

Everything works fine if the controller is invoked directly via a route for that area. However, if it's called via another controller outside of the area, i.e. via 'new SomeController().SomeAction()', the templates are not used, even if explicitly specified (the view is returned ok, but shows just default textboxes etc).

What could be the reason for this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Where are your templates located (in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`)?

Comment: Did you actually initialize the controller after `new SomeController()`? It needs `ControllerContext` to work correctly

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: they are in Area//Views/Some/EditorTemplates and found ok if controller is called directly

Comment: @haim770: what exactly do you mean? The controller in the area is called using 'new SomeController().SomeAction()', should I pass something else?

Comment: If you put them in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder, they should be found by all controllers.

Comment: @devlock, When `ViewResult` is involved, you better use the `ControllerFactory` / `ActionInvoker` to correctly mimic the regular behavior.

Comment: yes, they do get found when in views/shared, but from an organisational point of view they really belong in the area, so if possible they should stay there; I'd also love to understand why they're not used in this scenario (after all, it's the area controller returning the view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your action is invoked merely using `ctrl.Action()`, the current `RouteData` will be used (with the current `area/controller/action` values in it) and when Razor tries to resolve your `EditorTemplates` paths it consults the `ViewContext` that is still containing the (now wrong) values of the originating action.

You better use the `ControllerFactory` in order to mimic the desired behavior:

```
var ctrlFactory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();

var routeData = new RouteData();
routeData.DataTokens.Add("area", "target_area_name");
routeData.Values.Add("controller", "target_controller_name");
routeData.Values.Add("action", "target_action_name");

var requestContext = new RequestContext(this.HttpContext, routeData);
var ctrl = ctrlFactory.CreateController(requestContext, "target_controller_name") as TargetControllerType;

if (ctrl != null)
{
    ctrl.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(requestContext, ctrl);

    var ctrlDesc = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(typeof(TargetControllerType));
    var actionDesc = ctrlDesc.FindAction(ctrl.ControllerContext, "target_action_name");

    var result = actionDesc.Execute(ctrl.ControllerContext, new Dictionary<string, object>()) as ActionResult;

    this.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] = "target_area_name";
    this.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "target_controller_name";
    this.RouteData.Values["action"] = "target_action_name";

    return result;
}
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbuilder(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: I'm well impressed by this snippet, it works, too, but sadly the result is the same (templates ignored)

Comment: @devlock, Did you fill-in the correct values for `area`, `controller` and `action`?

Comment: I believe so, the controller action is executed without problems, just the templates not rendered

Comment: @devlock, I have updated the answer. It's now a little less elegant but should work.